# Converting data validation formula1 to relative/absolute

Tags: excel, vba

Im trying to convert validation.formula1 to absolute/relative with line:

```
Cells(Target.row, 6).Validation.Formula1 = Application.ConvertFormula(Cells(Target.row, 6).Validation.Formula1, 1, 1, 1)
```

but I get `Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment` error. Number of arguments is correct so there seems to be a problem with Formula1 assignment?

Comment: `Formula1` is read only, `Validation.Modify` should be helpful.

Comment: @BrakNicku `Cells(Target.row, 6).Validation.Modify Formula1:=Application.ConvertFormula(Cells(Target.row, 6).Validation.Formula1, 1, 1, 1)` returns `Application defined or object defined error`

Comment: Might be because `Formula1` property returns formula in local language and `ConvertFormula` only accepts English version. There is no built-in way of translating formula, only some workarounds.